# Factoring code of Data triggers bound to different properties

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a datagrid bound to a list of a custom "model" class.
In one of the cell I have 4 rectangles, representing 4 different string properties of my model class.

The rectangles are supposed to be black if the corresponding property is empty, red otherwise. 
I achieve this using a DataTrigger on each rectangle and it works fine but i have to write four time the same datatrigger with only the bound path changing. It seems like it could be more efficient.

Is there a clever way to define a DataTrigger once, and use a different bound path for each element (in my case rectangles) it is applied to ?

Thanks.

This is my model class:

```cs
class myModel
{
    [...]
    public string pr1 { get; set; }
    public string pr2 { get; set; }
    public string pr3 { get; set; }
    public string pr4 { get; set; }
    [...]
}
```

This is the datagrid bound to a `List<myModel>` :

```xml
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="200" Name="myDg" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        [...]
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="prs">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel  Name="spRow" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Rectangle Height="15" Name="rPr1" Width="10">
                            <Rectangle.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
                                    <Setter Property="Rectangle.Stroke" Value="Red"/>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=pr1}" Value="">
                                            <Setter Property="Rectangle.Stroke" Value="Black"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Rectangle.Style>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Rectangle Height="15" Name="rPr2" Width="10">
                            <Rectangle.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
                                    <Setter Property="Rectangle.Stroke" Value="Red"/>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=pr2}" Value="">
                                            <Setter Property="Rectangle.Stroke" Value="Black"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Rectangle.Style>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Rectangle Height="15" Name="rPr3" Width="10">
                            <Rectangle.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
                                    <Setter Property="Rectangle.Stroke" Value="Red"/>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=pr3}" Value="">
                                            <Setter Property="Rectangle.Stroke" Value="Black"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Rectangle.Style>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Rectangle Height="15" Name="rPr4" Width="10">
                            <Rectangle.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
                                    <Setter Property="Rectangle.Stroke" Value="Red"/>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=pr4}" Value="">
                                            <Setter Property="Rectangle.Stroke" Value="Black"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Rectangle.Style>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways...

**Solution 1:**

You can generalize the style at the ancestor level and then specialize the model properties in each rectangle.

The way you can do this is by biding specific `pr` property to `Tag` of each Rectangle and then use `Tag` as a generic data trigger source.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBox Margin="5" x:Name="MyTextBox1" Text="pr1" />
        <TextBox Margin="5" x:Name="MyTextBox2" Text="pr2" />
        <TextBox Margin="5" x:Name="MyTextBox3" Text="pr3" />
        <TextBox Margin="5" x:Name="MyTextBox4" Text="pr4" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="20"/>
                <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black"/>
                <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger
                          Binding="{Binding Tag,
                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                          Value="">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <Rectangle Tag="{Binding Text, ElementName=MyTextBox1, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <Rectangle Tag="{Binding Text, ElementName=MyTextBox2, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <Rectangle Tag="{Binding Text, ElementName=MyTextBox3, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <Rectangle Tag="{Binding Text, ElementName=MyTextBox4, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

So in above example when you clear the individual textbox you get a corresponding red rectangle. Notice that we have used Tag through a `DataTrigger` but we can also use a normal Trigger...

```
<Trigger Property="Tag" Value="">
    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
</Trigger>
```

**Solution 2:**

Use `ItemsControl` and then 4 (or `n`) items in your model to hold pr1..pr4 values.

**EDIT**

**....**

Change you model to include a list of `pr` objects. I am using `SourceFilter` class **just to hold** the two way editable string value that was held by `pr'n'` properties... You can use **any** class that holds a string value through a property.

```
    public List<SourceFilter> pr
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

Then I load the four properties as four `SourceFilter` objects...

```
    pr = new List<SourceFilter>();
    pr.Add(new SourceFilter("pr1"));
    pr.Add(new SourceFilter("pr2"));
    pr.Add(new SourceFilter("pr3"));
    pr.Add(new SourceFilter("pr4"));
```

And then I use ItemsControl's `ItemPanel`, `ItemsTemplate`, `ItemsSource` to achieve exactly same effect from Step 1...

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding pr, ElementName=MyWindow2}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Margin="5"
                         Text="{Binding Path=Source,
                                        Mode=TwoWay,
                                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding pr, ElementName=MyWindow2}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="20"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black"/>
                        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source}" Value="">
                                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataTemplate.Resources>
                <Rectangle />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Advantage is here you do not have to specify specific pr1..pr4 bindings anywhere. Plus its extensible (as `pr` can hold any `n` values and will generate same number of rectangles automatically).

Comment: Tried your first solution and it works great. The second one might come handy if the number of rectanglez can change at runtime. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create a class that derives from `DataTrigger` and has the unchanging details pre-set:

```
  public class RedBlackDataTrigger : DataTrigger
  {
    public RedBlackDataTrigger()
    {
      Value = string.Empty;
      Setters.Add(new Setter(Rectangle.StrokeProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)));
    }
  }
```

You can use it in XAML and just add the binding:

```
    <Rectangle Height="15" Width="10">
    <Rectangle.Style>
        <Style TargetType ="Rectangle">
            <Setter Property="Rectangle.Stroke" Value="Red"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Your-Namespace:RedBlackDataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=pr4}" />
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Rectangle.Style>
    </Rectangle>
```

Since you are also duplicating your `Style`, you can take it a step further and create a derived style class:

```
  public class RectangleStyle : Style
  {
    public RectangleStyle()
    {
      TargetType = typeof (Rectangle);
      Setters.Add(new Setter(Rectangle.StrokeProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)));
    }

    public string ColorTrigger
    {
      set
      {
        Triggers.Add(new RedBlackDataTrigger {Binding = new Binding(value) });
      }
    }
  }
```

Now you've reduced things to:

```
  <Rectangle Height="15" Width="10">
      <Rectangle.Style>
           <Your-Namespace:RectangleStyle ColorTrigger="pr4" />
      </Rectangle.Style>
  </Rectangle>
```

You can even take it one step further and create a derived `Rectangle` class to do it all.

Comment: angelWPF solution suits better my needs in this situation. But I like your solution and will use it in another part of my project. Thank you.